# Shared Hashref of hashes possible?

Tags: perl

Im trying to use a hashref of hashes to store a persistant field and a timestamp of when that field was changed.

It needs to be shared though as I have 2 threads that are required to access it although only one sets the values.

here is my current code with several commented out variations:

```
my $status = {};
share($status);
sub get_status {
    my($raid) = @_;
    return $status->{$raid}->{status} if exists $status->{$raid};
    return 1;
}
sub set_status {
    my($raid,$newstatus) = @_;
    my %t;
    $t{status} = $newstatus;
    $t{timestamp} = Time::HiRes::time;
    $status->{$raid} = \%t;
    #$status->{$raid} = {
        #status => $newstatus,
        #timestamp => Time::HiRes::time()
    #};
    #$status->{$raid}->{status}=$newstatus;
    #$status->{$raid}->{timestamp} = Time::HiRes::time;
    return 1;
}
set_status('680','1');
get_status('680');
```

I continually get `Invalid value for shared scalar at ./hashtest line 19.`

Could anyone help please :D?

Comment: `$status->{$raid} = whatever`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This perlmonks page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=259551) should explain the problem. One of the posts claims:

> You can share nested hash, as long as the internal hashes are also marked as shared.

You can try something like this:

```
share( %t );
$status->{ $raid } = \%t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the article, it provided a very detailed answer :D

Comment: You can also share the integer reference to the hashref, and use lock to prevent accessing the data at the same time.

Comment: the integer reference is dynamic called from other places. However locking the hashref is something i do need to look into. thanks for the input :D